# Stored NSMutableArray in NSMutableDictionary gets empty?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In my project I am storing `NSMutableArray` in `NSMutableDictionary`.I am performing this task in a `FOR` loop.The actual situation is,

within for loop

1.Firstly I stored some object in `NSMutableArray`.

2.Stored this `NSMutableArray` in `NSMutableDictionary` with key.

3.Then removing all objects in `NSMutableArray` before iteration.

my problems, if I NSLog `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionay` after step 2, I can see the  objects in array and dictionary.But after step 3, if I NSLog `NSMutableDictionay`,only keys are displayed,Objects in dictionary also removed.What I am wrong.Please suggest some solution.

This is the code I am using in project.

```
 for (int j=0; j<wordsofline.count; j++) {
     NSString *importstr=[wordsofline objectAtIndex:j];
     NSString *importtrim=[importstr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

     if ([importtrim rangeOfString:@"FROM"].location != NSNotFound) {
         NSArray *splitImportMIB = [importtrim componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
         NSLog(@"array %@ ,,,%@",splitImportMIB,muArrImport);
        [muDictImport setObject:muArrImport forKey:[splitImportMIB objectAtIndex:1]];
         NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",muDictImport);
        [muArrImport removeAllObjects];
         NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",muDictImport);
         break;
         }

      if (![importtrim isEqualToString:@""] && [importtrim rangeOfString:@"FROM"].location == NSNotFound) {
        [muArrImport addObject:importtrim];
         }

 }
```

Thank You.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Hai I have edited my code please check.

Comment: Of course. You are assigning the pointer then removing all objects in that pointer.

Comment: why `break` is there?

Comment: @Desdenova : How can I manage this situation?I want to remove all object from array before starting next iteration.Do you have any idea?

Comment: You are calling the method "removeAllObjects" for same instance which you are saving into dictionary.

Comment: When I find FROM string in the file I am breaking the loop.

Comment: How about, creating a fresh `NSMutableArray` for each iteration?

Comment: I tried that too.Not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you store something mutable in a container, you must stop using that mutable object from outside the container. Otherwise, your modifications will be reflected in objects that you have already stored.

For example, if you create a mutable array, populate it with data, store it at some key, and then clear the array, the stored array will be cleared as well. This is because the stored array and the array that you clear are really the same object: collections store references to objects that you pass.

To avoid this, make an immutable copy before storing your array, for example by using

```
[muDictImport setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:muArrImport]
                 forKey:[splitImportMIB objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: So I should store my MutableArray in separate array and then store it using new array in a Dictionary. right?

Comment: @NSUserDefault You are welcome! If you would like the stored array to remain mutable, you can either make a mutable copy, or create a new array to replace the `muArrImport` immediately after placing the current one in the array, i.e. call `muArrImport = [NSMutableArray array];` right after the `setObject:forKey:` call.